# ¿Por qué no puedo renderizar blobs obtenidos de Firebase Storage en un <img/> con React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, imagen, blob

en otras partes he cargado imágenes desde el ordenador para renderizarla sin problema en un `<img/>` y una `src` obtenida de un `File` con `URL.createObjectURL()`, lo de siempre.

Ahora, estoy obteniendo `Blobs` de Firebase, y uso el mismo método `URL.createObjectURL()` para hacer la URL para el src del .

Este es el momento en que renderizo la imagen:

```
       previewImages ? (
        <img
          key={'preview-img' + i}
          style={{ maxWidth: 200, height: 'auto', marginLeft: 16 }}
          src={previewImages[0]}
          alt={'preview-description-image' + i}
        />
      ) : (
        <Skeleton
          key={'skeleton-image' + i}
          style={{ marginLeft: 16 }}
          animation='wave'
          width={200}
          height={200}
        />
```

Y así obtengo los Blobs, que he confirmado que existen y que son devueltos por Firebase correctamente:

```
const handleDownloadImagesFromFirebase = () => {
    const imgPaths = answers.filter(
      (answer) => typeof answer.desc === 'object'
    );
    downloadImagesFirebase(imgPaths)
      .then((URLs) => {
        return Promise.all(
          URLs.map((URL) =>
            fetch(URL, {
              method: 'GET'
            })
          )
        );
      })
      .then((responses) => {
        return Promise.all(
          responses.map((response) => new Response(response).blob())
        );
      })
      .then((blobImgs) => {
        //const imgPathsCopy = [...imgPaths];
        const objURLs = blobImgs.map((blobImg) => {
          return URL.createObjectURL(blobImg);
        });
        console.log(objURLs);
        setPreviewImages(objURLs);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        handleOpenSnackbar(
          'error',
          'Error obteniendo imágenes. Revise su conexión y vuelva a intentarlo. Actualice su página o reabra las respuestas.'
        );
      });
  };
```

Algo engorroso pero funciona, ahí pueden ver el setPreviewImages(). Efectivamente aparece el Skeleton cuando el arreglo es nulo, este es el state inicialmente:

```
  const [previewImages, setPreviewImages] = useState(null);
```

Ahí está el Skeleton mientras se obtienen las imágenes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora fijense en lo que me muestra (cuando están cargadas las imágenes en previewImages):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Eso de Texto es solo una opción que está correcta.

Aquí están los URL que se asignan en previewImages cuando se cargan de todas las promesas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya intenté convertir el Blob en File, no funcionó, pero eso no debería ser el problema.

Comment: Quizá te esta faltando una cabecera de encoding, quien sabe, yo veo tu código y todo parece estar en su lugar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En vez de esto:

```
.then((responses) => {
    return Promise.all(
       responses.map((response) => new Response(response).blob())
    );
})
```

Intenta esto:

```
.then((responses) => {
    return Promise.all(
       responses.map((response) => response.blob())
    );
})
```

Comment: No hace falta decir que tambien hay que mirar que las URL, de firebase esten correctas, mira si estan correctas y los recursos son accesibles.

Comment: Hola, así lo tenía inicialmente, pero si no hago una instancia de Response, el blop() me devuelve una promesa y no el Blob. Entonces, al ponerlo como lo primero que pones, me devuelve los blobs sin problema.

Comment: Cierto, revisaré bien que estoy obteniendo.

Comment: Amigo, tienes toda la razón. Me sirvió lo que dice tu respuesta... Muchas gracias. Parece que cuando vi lo que dije en mi comentario anterior, era lo contrario... MUCHAS GRACIAS, estuve atascado por tal tontería...

Comment: Que extraño amigo... pero me alegro que te haya funcionado, me parece extraño porque se supone que Response entonces fue creado por algo, a lo mejor nos falta mirar mas a fondo el objeto Response, (por que te deberia funcionar tanto con Response como sin el si lo estamos usando bien).

Comment: Es que creo que ya obtenía un "Response", entonces lo encapsulaba con otro "Response" y me terminaba generando un response del objeto response, puse la consola a ver que me devolvía eso que dice blobs, y al final eran unos textos planos, quizás la fuente del response convertida a cadena.